# Qweb with odoo 9 how can i prevent table row split between two page

Tags: odoo-9, qweb

hello i want to print a table in my report with thead who is repeat in each page my problem is that my lines divide between two pages and it mixes with thead.
 
i work with odoo 9
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmm6o.jpg)
thank you

Comment: I do not understand your question, could you show some screenshot? If some table does not fit in your current page, then the table is going to continue in the next page repeating the table header. That's the normal behaviour

Comment: hello ChesuCR i have added  a screenshot thank you

Comment: Make sure you are using the right [wkhtmltopdf version](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html#enterprise): `0.12.1 qt patched`